# C#.NET: Programmatically export Crystal Report to XML using defined XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, crystal-reports

I have a few crystal reports created.  So far I have developed an app that passes values to a CR and produces a XML file of that report.  However, CR has a default XSD specified.  Within CR itself you have the option to change the default XSD.  I want to also change this XSD programatically.  This is what I have so far.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cryRpt.Load(@"somerpt.rpt");
    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("someuser", "somepass");
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("val1", "1");
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("val2", "2");
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("val3", "3");
    cryRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Xml,  "someloc\test.xml");
}
```

So the issue I"m having is the xml that is produced needs to be based on another XSD.  I'm trying to do this via CR first using CR objects.  But if I can't I guess the long and hard way of doing it would be to setup a dataset and somehow convert this dataset to a xml via xsd.

Comment: are you familiar with the fact that you can convert the DataSet.DataTable[0] to XML do a simple `C# stackoverflow convert datatable to xml` type that in your browser.. plenty of working examples

Comment: The CR is performing that data requests to the database.  The .NET is just facilitating the "plugin of values".  Is it possible to fetch the data coming from CR within .NET?  I understand there are many examples of creating XML from a dataset etc...